# About datagridview control's event handling

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

i want to raise the datagridview's CellValueChanged() event in the textbox's KeyPress() event.

can anybody help me?

thanx....

Comment: Why would you like to do something like this? The `CellValueChanged`event is triggered automatically when the cell value has changed.

Comment: actually i want to handle the keypress event for the datagridview. when user enters the input in the datagridview's cell. depending on this i want to manipulate the data from the datagridview. But when i was using the keypress event for this then i'm unable to select the current cell value of the datagridview. It shows null value to the datagridview current cell value. so that's why i asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to invoke `ValueChangedEventHandler()` in the `KeyPressEventHangler()`. Or its considered to be a bad practise...